# whereBetween dates trouble for getting results in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some trouble with getting the correct output of a Eloquent Query.

```
$checkIn  = date(request()->checkin);
$checkOut = date(request()->checkout);

$bookedRooms = App\Booking::whereBetween('checkin', [$checkin, $checkout])->whereBetween('checkout', [$checkin, $checkout])->pluck('room_id');
$availabileRooms = App\Room::whereNotIn('id', $bookedRooms->toArray())->sum('number_of_rooms');
```

What I have is a checkin and checkout date.

It is a database for a Hotel.
The Hotel has Rooms. There a different types of Rooms, and each Room can exist multiple times. That is set in the Room-table with an integer value of the rooms available in column `number_of_rooms`

What I want, it the output of the percentage that is still available of a specific Room and the total availability of Rooms in the date range.

I thought that it can be achieved with the code given before, but that can be not.

Can someone help me out? Probably it's simpler then I can think of now..

Answer (score 0):

i looked your code, but could you please tell me one thing. what is the date format of checkin and checkout you getting.

make sure that you getting date format is like 2019-07-04 (YYYY-mm-dd).

i hope this will help you.

Comment: That is really not the issue here. Thats where the ```date()``` is for.